# AndroidStudio LG K130ee not recognised

Tags: android, lg

I want to run app on my device. When I connect my LG device through USB there is no reaction, no notifications, only charging (both on Mac and Windows). In AndroidStudio it is also not shown under "Connected devices". I did a little research and found a similar problem here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/g4/help/usb-connection-phone-detected-pc-t3291549
This user solved it by enabling Port Check Test but I can't do it because it says "Disabled" and nothing happens when I click it. Does anybody have an idea what to do ? Factory resets, enabling USB debugging etc. did not help. What is weird - it used to normally work a few months ago.

Comment: You need to install a driver specific to LG phones.

Comment: @jreft56 see my answer sir hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this software

It is used to connect any android device to android studio

http://pdanet.co/bin/PdaNetA4197.exe

Answer (score 0):

You can download LG-specific drivers from http://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware-drivers. Since this is the official LG website, I trust it more than some random domain.

Comment: Unfortunately, no changes

Comment: @jreft56 Do you have any other USB cables? Some cables are power-only and will not transfer data. I suggest that you test multiple cables to see if you can get Windows or Mac to detect the device as a drive.

Comment: Please read my whole post. I wrote it used to work. It is the same cable I used before. I think something weird happened with the device.

Comment: @jreft56 I still suggest you try a different cable and/or port.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue with my HTC device in Ubuntu.And the solution for that is

> 1) First enable your USB debugging.
>
> 2) Change your mode do not put it on only charging mode set the mode
>   File Transfer mode.
>
> 3) Once you set the File Transfer your device prompt with dialog which
>   says allow this computer... bla bla...etc. Check that box and you are
>   ready to run the app on your device.

*Note: If you didn't get that dialog try to unplugged the port and plugged in again.*

As you said your device is just charging and do nothing.Try above stuff if it is not working then try to change the cable and then try again.

Reason to change the cable is their are many cables are available in the market which are only for charging. I have that kind of cable for Samsung Tab 2 which do only charging and apart from that it doing nothing. When I connect to my PC it will just charging and do nothing. So It may be a chance that your cable is only for charging so try to change the cable first.